# Use background-size property in a div

Tags: css

I've a `div` with multi background images:

```
<div style="background-image: url(lines.png) bottom center, url(bg.png) bottom center">
    ....
</div>
```

How can I specify that the `background-size: cover` should be applied on the second image only ?

Thanks.

Comment: create 2 div separately and add class name and put them under same parent div

Comment: background-size: auto, cover;  => lines.png => size auto;bg.png => cover

Answer (score 1):

As simple as adding a `,` between the values you want. Also, you should follow the order of your images.

Check out the following example, i'm adding two images as background-image and i'm following the same order to add the values of `background-repeat` and `background-size`
in this example the first image will get `background-repeat: no-repeat` and `background size:auto`.

The second image will get the second value of each property.

```css
.mybackground {
  background-image: url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11991/startransparent.gif"), url("https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6457/mdn_logo_only_color.png");
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-size: auto, cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybackground">
  yo
</div>
```